# Nativescript Vue using tns preview failing

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

Using `tns preview` is suddenly failing for my NS-Vue project with the following error after I scan the QR code.

```
Project successfully prepared (android)
Start sending initial files for device Nexus 6P (2e6517cd-cc2c-45a8-8915-525d6e437822).
Successfully sent initial files for device Nexus 6P (2e6517cd-cc2c-45a8-8915-525d6e437822).
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at PreviewSdkService.<anonymous> (/Users/Quokka/.nvm/versions/node/v13.9.0/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/livesync/playground/preview-sdk-service.js:100:43)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/Quokka/.nvm/versions/node/v13.9.0/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/livesync/playground/preview-sdk-service.js:4:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I've tried `rm -rf node_modules` and doing an `npm install` afterwards however, it still doesn't work. Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a migration going on with the NativeScript playground. The issue should be fixed by now.